# Load raw data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

There is data for Students table provided in a csv file.
DDL to create the table :

```
Create Table students 
(
    Student_Name nvarchar(50),
    S1 int,
    S2 int,
    S3 int
);
```

Sample data in the file :

```
Student_Name,S1,S2,S3
John Doe,92,90,98
John,88,78,54
```

To load this I have built an insert into values code block for the entire file which looks something like this:

```
insert into Students values
('John Doe',92,90,98),
('John',88,78,549)
```

Another approach I tried is SQL server import tasks, with this all the data ended in the strings format. Had to cast/convert the data again into the `int` format for the `S1,S2 and S3` columns.

Are there any ways other the these to load the data in the easiest way possible?

Comment: for column conversion, please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/column-conversion-details-dialog-box-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15.   At the end of the wizard there is an option to SAVE it, which makes it easy to re-use.

Comment: the link to the save&run: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/save-and-run-package-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: During the import task you can specify the data type, take a look at this link towards the end - https://www.sqlshack.com/importexport-data-sql-server-using-sql-server-import-export-wizard/

Comment: You could [create a format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server) describing your .csv data, then use either [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) from within SQL server, or push it in from externally using the [bcp.exe utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility).

Answer (score -1):

You can use  select * into Newtable or InsertInto ExistingTable from Datatable.
for example

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, e.JobTitle, a.AddressLine1, a.City,   
    sp.Name AS [State/Province], a.PostalCode  
INTO dbo.EmployeeAddresses  
FROM Person.Person AS c  
    JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS e   
    ON e.BusinessEntityID = c.BusinessEntityID  
    JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea  
    ON e.BusinessEntityID = bea.BusinessEntityID  
    JOIN Person.Address AS a  
    ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID  
    JOIN Person.StateProvince as sp   
    ON sp.StateProvinceID = a.StateProvinceID;  
GO
```

Comment: This answer is no way related to this question.